# Is it a bad practice to put all the images in a single table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm creating a small community using the Symfony2 Framework and backboneJS.
When I took a look at the database today I realized that it might be wrong to store all images using this schema.

ImageTable

1. Id
2. Title
3. Owner
4. Description
5. Url

So when a user logs in and wants to have a look at his own images, I just loop through all images where owner == currentuser.
Is this a bad practice?
The more owners I have the longer the query its going to take, right?
I'm asking since it might take a week to restructure the whole website database and I don't want to fix what might not be broken.

I know a solution might be to set a manytomany relationship between the current user table and an own image table, but is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is as normalized as it gets for your scenario. A many to many relationship is **not** what you are looking for, since a user may have multiple images, but an image can't have multiple owners (or can they?).

So if the `Owner` is a foreign key for the table `user` you are good.